# Multi-Dimensional Container in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, containers

I searched around on Google, but I was unable to find any libraries for a multi-dimensional container in Java (preferably one that supports generics as well).  I could easily write one (in fact, I have started to), but I was hoping that I would be able to reuse the work someone else has done for the sake of efficiency.  I don't necessarily need to provide any sort of additional functionality outside of the "container" realm (AKA, no matrix functionality for example).

Does anybody know of any type of class/library for a multi-dimensional container?  Thanks!

**Edit**: To clarify, yes, I am looking for a Collection of Collections of Collections ... (or int[][][][][], etc).  Essentially, a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: could you please be more specific?  Maybe "multi-dimensional container" is a term with a very specific meaning, but I've never heard it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, a Collection of Collections?

```
Collection<Collection<Object>> multiDimensional = 
                     new ArrayList<Collection<Object>>();
```

Or something completely different?

Answer (score 3):

[Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) supports [multimaps](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) and [multisets](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) (bags). Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use a jagged array (eg `int[][]`)?

You can make it n-dimensional (`int[][][][]`), but it starts to get silly after a while

Comment: you really can't imagine a four-dimensional array? ;-)

Comment: @thecoop - This is essentially what I want.  However, I need the array to be able to grow at a later time (add additional dimensions, as well as add values within the already existing dimensions).  That's why I was hoping to utilize the Collections framework.

Comment: That'll be a List<List<Integer>> then